# What is the difference between onclick(function(){}) and on('click',function(){}) function in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to load pages in one div using ajax :
this is my HTML code :

```
 <ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
    <li><a href="#" id="m_blink">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="d_blink">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="k_blink">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='home'></div>
```

When i am calling the pages in one div that is 'home' div like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#m_blink").onclick(function() {
        $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
     });

     $("#d_blink").onclick(function() { 
        $("#home").load("tab2.php",{},function(){});
     });

     $("#k_blink").onclick(function() { 
        $("#home").load("tab3.php",{},function(){});
     });
});
```

In chrome and Firefox when i inspect element the error is :

In chrome :

'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'

and in firefox :

[12:15:46.575] TypeError: $(...).onclick is not a function

and when i changed my jquery code to like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#m_blink").on('click', function() {
        $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
     });

     $("#d_blink").on('click',function() { 
        $("#home").load("tab2.php",{},function(){});
     });

     $("#k_blink").on('click',function() { 
        $("#home").load("tab3.php",{},function(){});
     });
});
```

When i execute this code this is working , what is the difference between the onclick functions in jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `onclick` function in jquery. So the error is correct and self-explanatory.

```
TypeError: $(...).onclick is not a function
```

You should use [**.click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/), which is a shortcut for `.on("click", handler)`

```
$(selector).click(function() {
});
```

Comment: Thanks , i am confused.

Comment: @John, Why are you confused?